Stokes' theorem and vector continuity equations
I have been working with homogeneous continuity equations of the general form:
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{J}=0$$
This has me wondering whether we can formulate other equations with a similar structure but employing Stokes' theorem instead of Gauss' theorem, and of course whether these equations have physical meaning. For instance, an equation of this kind in its integral form would be:
$$\int_S\frac{\partial \vec{\rho}}{\partial t}\cdot d\vec{S}+\int_P\vec{J}\cdot d\vec{l}=0$$
where $S$ is an arbitrary open surface and $P$ is its boundary. Using Stokes' theorem, this equation can be reduced to its differential form:
$$\frac{\partial \vec{\rho}}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{J}=0$$
Another proposal for the analogous equations can be thought of using Stokes' theorem in reverse:
$$\int_P\frac{\partial \vec{\rho}}{\partial t}\cdot d\vec{l}+\int_S(\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{J})\cdot d\vec{S}=0$$
again, in its differential form, this would be:
$$\frac{\partial \vec{\rho}}{\partial t}+\vec{J}=0$$
which can be solved directly for either one of the magnitudes, through differentiation for $\vec{J}$ and integration for $\vec{\rho}$, although in this case $\vec{J}$ would not be completely determined as we would still be free to add to it any function $f(\vec{r})$ we liked, since the partial derivative is with respect to time.

You ain't seen nothing yet! Wait until you learn to express electromagnetism in terms of the language of differential forms, as it turns out, Gauss' law, Stokes law, Green's theorem, are all unified in the generalized Stokes law, absolutely gorgeous stuff. You will get a kick out of it.

As an example of the physical meaning behind such manipulations; Faraday's law is of the form of your first differential relation:
$$\nabla\times\vec E+{\partial\vec B\over\partial t}=0.$$
We can integrate over an arbitrary open surface bounded by $\partial S$, to get:
$$\int_S(\nabla\times\vec E)\cdot\mathbf{\hat n}\; d(S)+\int_S{\partial\vec B\over\partial t}\cdot\mathbf{\hat n}\; d(S)=0.$$
Applying Stokes' law we have:
$$\int_{\partial S}\vec E\cdot\mathbf{\hat t}\; d(\partial S)+\int_S{\partial\vec B\over\partial t}\cdot\mathbf{\hat n}\; d(S)=0$$
Since $\partial S$ is a closed loop, the line integral of $\vec E$ over $\partial S$ is the EMF induced in the loop due to the time varying magnetic flux through the surface $S$, i.e. Lenz's law:
$$\mathscr{E}={\partial\Phi\over\partial t},$$
where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux through $S$.

Right, how could I not think of that example, it was right before my eyes!
